# Reset Form After Form Submit in Template driven Form Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm using `angular 2.4.0` and I want to clear input fields after form submit.
Tried `SendRequest.reset()`.

component.ts

```
getRevision(SendRequest: NgForm){
     this.submitted = true;
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    let params = {
      "Firstname":this.name,
      "Lastname":"",
      "Email":this.email,
      "Phonecode":"91",
      "Phone":this.phone,
      "Message":this.message,      
      }
    return this.http.post(this.url,params)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(this.errorHandler)
    .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.revisions = data.resultData;
                this.resultCode = data.resultCode;
                this.responeseMsg = data.message.MessageText;                
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            },
            () =>{
             SendRequest.resetForm();
             SendRequest.form.reset();
            }
        )

  }
```

component.html

```
 <form #SendRequest="ngForm" [formGroup]="SendRequest" >
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Your Name" required  #fullname="ngModel">
     <div *ngIf="fullname.errors && (fullname.dirty || fullname.touched)"
     class="contact-validate">
     <div [hidden]="!fullname.errors.required">
       Name is required
     </div>                                     
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="email" required  #emailid="ngModel"  placeholder="Your Email" pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$">
   <div *ngIf="emailid.errors && (emailid.dirty || emailid.touched)"
   class="contact-validate">
   <div [hidden]="!emailid.errors.required">
     Email is required
   </div>
   <div [hidden]="!emailid.errors.pattern">
     Please enter valid email format
   </div>                                     
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="phone" placeholder="Your Phone" required  pattern="[0-9]+"  #phoneno="ngModel">
 <div *ngIf="phoneno.errors && (phoneno.dirty || phoneno.touched)"
 class="contact-validate">
 <div [hidden]="!phoneno.errors.required">
   Phone is required
 </div>    
 <div [hidden]="!phoneno.errors.pattern">
   Phone must be number
 </div>                                                         
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <textarea class="form-control" name="message" [(ngModel)]="message" #msg="ngModel" required placeholder="Your Message" rows="7"></textarea>
   <div *ngIf="msg.errors && (msg.dirty || msg.touched)"
   class="contact-validate">
   <div [hidden]="!msg.errors.required">
     Message is required
   </div>                                     
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="send-msg-btn">
  <button type="button" [disabled]="!SendRequest.form.valid" (click)="getRevision()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-send"></i>send message</button>      
</div>
</form>
```

I'm calling `getRevision()` on button click, tried
`SendRequest.resetForm();`
`SendRequest.form.reset();`
already but not working
Please give me suggestions, what is wrong here.

Comment: send the variable "SendRequest" with the method call in button click event, getRevision(SendRequest)

Comment: hey, let me know if [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45183145/2545680) worked for you

Comment: @Maximus Thans for answer, I'm checking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `reset` method on the `FormGroup` created in your component and reference it with `this`:

```
this.SendRequest.reset();
```

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya, did Pengyy answer also work like this `SendRequest.reset(); ` without specifying form control values? I don't understand how it could work

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya, hmm, I don't understand how. The `NgForm` doesn't even have `reset` method [as shown in the docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm)

Comment: You are right, its not listed there but it might be ` host: {'(submit)': 'onSubmit($event)', '(reset)': 'onReset()'},` under Annotations

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya, can you please post your working code? I'll take a look

Comment: it has minor changes, same as Penggy  suggested

Comment: In the sense of `NgForm`  your answer should be considered as  right answer

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya, pengyy is correct, you can use `reset()` because you're not working with `formGroup` directive, but with `formGroup` class directly. You don't need to pass the `SendRequest` though, it should be available in the class already. See my update. Also I think you should accept the Pengyy answer.

Answer (score 7):

you shall pass `SendRequest`(form itself) at click event of `send message` button

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="!SendRequest.form.valid" (click)="getRevision(SendRequest)" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-send"></i>send message</button>
```

then call `form.reset()` to reset the template driven form.

```
getRevision(SendRequest: NgForm){
  ...
  SendRequest.reset();        // <-------reset form here
}
```

simple **[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nnwlk7O0UipuoJ3oyho8?p=preview)**.

Comment: hey, can you please explain why your solution works? the `NgForm` doesn't  seem to have `reset` method [as shown in the docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm). Also, why are the controls reset to empty if you don't specify the values for them? Thanks

Comment: @Maximus this is normal feature of HTML5 formElement, you can find its documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: but you're not working with native element, you're working with `NgForm` directive class instance

Comment: @Maximus I understand what confused you because this confused me for a while too.  but you can find the `reset()` method at `Ngform`'s prototype set, this one is a little deeper.

Comment: @Maximus Only `SendRequest.resetForm();` doing this is also working. I don't have to specify values in it

Comment: @Maximus the reason why I use `reset()` instead of `resetForm()` is because once I suffered a problem that `resetForm` cannot clear custom validator erros.

Comment: I see, thanks, let me explore this, I'll get back) Sorry for stealing your accept, I'll return it if you're right)

Comment: @Maximus That's all right. :-) BTW, I'm still using this at my project(@angular@4.2.3). Let me know if there are any new changes.

Comment: you were right, I can use `reset()` without values. thanks. see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182945/reset-form-after-form-submit-in-template-driven-form-angular2/45183145#comment77363804_45183145)